# htmlspecialchars and make links clickable

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I have a PHP script which processes user input. I need to escape all special characters, but also make links clickable (turn them into `<a>` elements). What I need is:

```
function specialCharsAndLinks($text) {
    // magic goes here
}
$inp = "http://web.page/index.php?a1=hi&a2=hello\n<script src=\"http://bad-website.com/exploit.js\"></script>";
$out = specialCharsAndLinks($inp);
echo $out;
```

The output should be (in HTML):

```
<a href="http://web.page/index.php?a1=hi&a2=hello">http://web.page/index.php?a1=hi&amp;a2=hello</a>
&lt;script src="http://bad-website.com/exploit.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

Note that the amperstand in the link stays in the `href` attribute, but is converted to `&amp;` in the actual content of the link.

When viewed in a browser:

http://web.page/index.php?a1=hi&a2=hello
<script src="http://bad-website.com/exploit.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

I eventually solved it with:

```
function process_text($text) {
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
    $url_regex = "/(?:http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(?:\/\S*)?/";
    $text = preg_replace_callback($url_regex, function($matches){
        return '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars_decode($matches[0]).'" rel="nofollow">'.$matches[0]."</a>";
    }, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

The first line html-encodes the input.
The second line defines the URL regex. Could be improved, but working for now.
The 3rd line uses `preg_replace_callback`, a function which is like `preg_replace`, but instead of supplying it with a replacement string, you supply a replacement *function* that returns the replacement string.
The 4th line is the actual function. It's quite self-documenting. `htmlspecialchars_decode` undoes the actions of `htmlspecialchars` (therefore making the link valid if it contained an amperstand).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$urlEscaped = htmlspecialchars("http://web.page/index.php?a1=hi&a2=hello");
$aTag = '<a href="$urlEscaped">Hello</a>';
echo $aTag;
```

Your example doesn't work because if escaping whole html tag, `a` tag will never get processed by the browser, instead it will just display as plain text.

As you can see, stackoverflow escapes our whole input (questions/answers ...), so we can actually see the code, and not letting browser to process it.

Comment: My example works perfectly. The link in the rendered output is an `<a>` tag.

Comment: You wanna say that you see 'Hello' only? (procesed tag)

Comment: Ok, so why not just decode the content?       <a>content</a>  htmlspecialchars_decode()

Comment: I can html-decode the URL (since that needs to be decoded, possibly url-encoded), but keep everything else the same way. Also, I have long text, where everything might not be the url, like in the new example. But now, I can't use a regex since preg_replace can't call functions.

Comment: I'm still confused with what you really want...  On the end of your question, by saying "When viewed in a browser:" did you mean that this is what you want or what you dont want? What kind of xss are you trying?

Comment: I mean, do you want a script to execute or not?

Comment: the 'viewed in a browser' is just the previous code without 4 spaces in the beginning (therefore stackoverflow renders it as html).